# Prove that every finite, nonempty set $B \subseteq A$ has an $R$- minimal element.

Tags: induction, relations

This is an example from Velleman's "How To Prove It":

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$. Prove that every finite, nonempty set $B \subseteq A$ has an $R$- minimal element.

I was trying to do the proof before looking at the solution, and the goal I came up with was $$\forall B \subseteq A ((\exists n \geq 1 (|B| = n)) \rightarrow \text{B has an $R$-minimal element)}$$

The goal given in the text was $$\forall n \geq 1 \forall B \subseteq A(\text{$B$ has $n$ elements $\rightarrow$ $B$ has a minimal element})$$

It seems as though the book's formulation of the goal allows us to prove it by induction, but is it possible (and correct) to prove the goal I wrote?

Comment: Ignore Zorn's lemma.... Induction proves statements of the form $\forall n \geq 1, P(n)$. The goal in the text is of this form. Your goal is not of this form.

Comment: It can be proved along the lines of your goal, but the proof by induction on $n$ is much simpler. Your approach requires quite a bit of preliminary work.